# ElseIf Statement In VB

Tags: vba, if-statement

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding an error in my VB code. I'm trying to design an `ElseIf statement` but I always get the error under each `ElseIf` that it must be preceeded by an `If statement`.

My code is along the lines of:

```
If Value1= 5 then Variable1 = 4
ElseIf Value1= 4 then Variable2 = 5
ElseIf Value1= 3 then Variable2 = 6
End If
```

So I have the if statement preceeding the `ElseIf statement`, but it still won't compile. Any idea why?

Comment: Syntax does not look correct.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
If Value1 = 5 Then
    Variable1 = 4
ElseIf Value1 = 4 Then
    Variable2 = 5
ElseIf Value1 = 3 Then
    Variable2 = 6
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first `If statement` is one liner and does not need `End If` to terminate.
 It is in a way *self-terminating* `If statement` and thus your succeeding `ElseIf's` are floating.
 One liner `If statements` is not applicable on `ElseIf contructs`.
 You can try what Tui posted which is the correct syntax.
 Or you can write your conditions like below:

```
If Value1= 5 then Variable1 = 4
If Value1= 4 then Variable2 = 5
If Value1= 3 then Variable2 = 6
```

The disadvantage is you cannot test for an `Else` statement but it will work the same way as what Tui posted. Although not related to the question, you can also try using `Select Case statement`. HTH.

```
Select Case Value1
Case 5: Variable1 = 4
Case 4: Variable2 = 5
Case 3: Variable2 = 6
End Select
```